# Hide-show login and register using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have problem with show-hide model in my webpage. 
When I click the link that is responsible for it, nothing happens.
I would like it to work taht when i click "Sign up" it will show me register-form and when i click "Login" i will hide register-form and show login-form.
Below is the code I wrote. 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="showhide.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login-page">
            <div class="form">
                <form class="register-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name:">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password:">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email:">
                    <button>Create</button>
                    <p class="message">Already Registered? <a href='#'>Login</a></p>
                </form>

                <form class="login-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <button>Login</button>
                    <p class="message">Not Registered? <a href="#">Sign up</a></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
   $('.message a').click(function(){
   $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
   });
```

Thank you in advance for your interest in my problem.

Comment: Do you want the form to animate/fade away or do you want to hide/show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target` is an element which fired an event, `.parent()` method returns its parent, in our case that would be the form, `.siblings()` method returns siblings of an element

```
$('.message a').click((e)=>{
   $(e.target).parent().parent().hide();
   $(e.target).parent().parent().siblings().show()
})
```

P.S if you want to add a fade effect to hide/show methods pass time(ms) argument to it. `hide(1000)/show(2000)`

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not working. I can add taht i am using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAOBXGPuKqo&t=900. And  everything works the same up to this point.

Comment: Both your script and mine work on the given page. Why don't they work good at my computer ?

Comment: Did you add `style="display: none"` to login form?

Comment: Yes,, i did it.

Comment: I think so because the script is in the same folder as the html file. And the script I add using `<script src="showhide.js"></script> ` in `<head></head>` section.

Comment: Use internal script instead. Like so `<script>$('.message a').click((e)=>{
   $(e.target).parent().parent().hide();
   $(e.target).parent().parent().siblings().show()
})</script>`

Comment: Also check the console

Comment: unfortunately nothing has changed.

Comment: In the console you can see that js is included. But the problem is that it does't detect clicking on the link and when we clik on it nothing happens.

Comment: send me screenshot of your js file please

Comment: https://ibb.co/s1KynDt
https://ibb.co/84cNtpC
https://ibb.co/4NcbnTt
https://ibb.co/51HHqft 
these are all my files

Comment: Try this https://pastebin.com/xjn9Murw and also see the console

Comment: Now everything works, thanks a lot. But my last question is why those scripts didn't work?

Comment: Because you were loading the script in head tag, it was loaded when document wasn't loaded yet so we needed to execute javascript code when whole document was loaded. `$(document).ready(function to execute when document loads)`

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ see full info about it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.